# How can I automatically create a sub class in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, composition

I have the following code:

```
public class Page {
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public int RoleNumber { get; set; }
    public class Navigation {
        public string Menu { get; set; }
        public string Breadcrumbs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I always need the Navigation class every time a new instance of a Page class is created. Is there a way I can have the Navigation class automatically created?

Comment: But you already have a "sub class".  What are you trying to do with it exactly?

Comment: But the subclass doesn't exist even if I create the main class. What I want to do is to have a method that creates menus and breadcrumbs and then returns them both. As it can only return one thing then I assume the only way to return more than one thing is to put them in a class and return that class.

Comment: @Angela you don't need to put the *class definition* inside `Page`, you need an *instance* of the class.

Comment: @dbaseman - but Navigation will always be part of page. I was thinking to keep things together it would be better to have Navigation as a sub class.

Comment: FYI the term "subclass" usually means a class that extends another class, as opposed to an internal class created inside the definition like you have here.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli: Is correct; what you have is a *nested* class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it would be best to use inheritance in this case.  You don't want to get into a situation with redundant code.

```
public class Navigation {
    public string Menu { get; set; }
    public string Breadcrumbs { get; set; }
}

public class Page : Navigation {
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public int RoleNumber { get; set; }    
}
```

Alternatively, you could instantiate an instance of `Navigation` in `Page`'s constructor:

```
public class Page {
    public Navigation PageNavigation { get; private set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public int RoleNumber { get; set; }    

    public Page() {
        PageNavigation = new Navigation();
    }

    public class Navigation {
        public string Menu { get; set; }
        public string Breadcrumbs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: These are two pretty different approaches. Inheritance doesn't look right to me; I think the composition approach is correct.

Comment: Please excuse my basic knowledge but do people normally use the underscore naming for private variables. Also thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: The Navigation class will always be a part of the page and will never be used outside of the Page context. Would it not be best for me to keep the two of them together?

Comment: @Angela yes, you're right.  I took out the private variable, since getter/setter seems more concise here.

Comment: @Angela sure, if that's the case, then keep the definition of `Navigation` inside `Page`, and add an instance of it also (updated my answer for this scenario).